# Raspberry locked in Blackscreen after editing /etc/profile

Tags: python, boot

Im Working on a Project, that on buttonpress via GPIO things would happen.
I got it working and wanted to add a way, that the Program starts on boot up. A quick search later i found this Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meeKv3DY9ps
Which I followed. My problem now is that the Raspberry is stuck on a Blackscreen and i dont have a way to edit the Pythonscript anymore.

The Pythoncode on its own works on bootup as intended but now the rest of the pi is unusable.

I know that i could simply delete and reinstall the SD-Card but i would prefer not as i have other programs on the Raspberry

I hope my Question is understandable and thanks in advance

Comment: Put the card in sd card reader take it to linux machine mount it and make your edits to disable the python script. Put it back in the machine and play with it some more.

Comment: DO NOT use `/etc/profile` for this purpose.  Make a note of whoever made that youtube garbage and never take any advice from them again -- this is the worst kind of [cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) practice peddled by people who do not know what they are doing in order to sucker people who know even less *so they can try for a profitable channel*.   It is not being helpful. You should be able to fix this if you can edit stuff in the root filesystem on another computer -- just remove whatever you added.

Comment: if you can boot your pi from USB then you won't need another linux computer - depends on which model pi you have

Comment: Please add the information what you have done into the question. it is bad practice to just refer to an external link to understand what you have done. There are other solutions than to use `/etc/profile` which is the worst solution.